# Why is my Entity Framework application working?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

To quickly get in to it, the models are:

```
public class foo{
public int ID;
[Required]
public bla bla;
}

public class bla{
public int ID;
public string test
}
```

Basically, this works fine and as expected.

My application is a normal application - I have a list of `bla`'s each of which is associated with a `foo`.

I have a page that has a list of Foos, and, someone can click on one which will then show every bla that is associated with that Foo.

The code has the ID of the Foo passed to it and is:

```
bla bla = db.bla.Where(x=>x.id == id);

db.foo.Where(x=>x.bla == bla);
```

However, I really wanted to experiment with the FluentAPI, and, I used the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<foo>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.bla)
                    .WithOptional()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

I am guessing from looking at the database schema that I have inadvertently created a one to one relationship because the `bla_id` column doesn't exist. However, what I really don't understand is how my application continues to work without modification? (all be it, I can only create a maximum of one foo per bla).

I don't really understand why `WithOptional` would imply one to one - this is really getting on my nerves as the tooltips for the different options (and MSDN) imply very similar, if not the same information between the options. It is making it very hard to learn.

Also, am I right in thinking that the FluentAPI overwrites model annotations completely?

Lastly, I have been struggling here a bit. Does anyone know of a cheat sheet/list for the FluentAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Configuring Relationships with Fluent API (Code First)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).

Scroll down to **Configuring a One-to–Zero-or-One Relationship**.